# SQL QUESTION, The sunday is the first day of a week?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the SQL below, in this SQL the Sunday will be the first day of a week?
For example, 2019/48 contains 2019-11-25_2019-12-01 or 2019-11-24_2019-11-30?

```
SELECT concat(CAST(year(pack_order.confirm_date_time) AS STRING), '/', CAST(weekofyear(pack_order.confirm_date_time) AS string)) AS time
```

Comment: In China,  the first day of a week is Monday! so I didn't know the SQL

Comment: You're taking a date and applying an expression to it. You realise you could substitute those dates you're asking about into this expression and find out for yourself far easier than asking here?

Comment: Is this database SQL Server? If so, tag the question accordingly.

Comment: the database is MySQL and hive SQL

Answer (score 0):

**WEEKOFYEAR()** is equivalent to **WEEK(date, 3)** .. thus Monday! is first taken as first day of the week.

possible values are:

- 0    Sunday  0-53 -  with a Sunday in this year
- 1    Monday  0-53 -  with 4 or more days this year
- 2    Sunday  1-53 -  with a Sunday in this year
- 3    Monday  1-53 -  with 4 or more days this year
  ...

if you need more control use the WEEK(date, mode)-Function

> https://database.guide/weekofyear-examples-mysql/

Comment: "*usually SQL starts weeks on sunday*" - not true. "SQL" (as in "the SQL standard") does not define any rules for the "start of the week" to begin with. If oyu have a specific database product in mind with that sentence, then please state the name of that product.

Comment: "*Everywhere the week starts on mondays*" is also not true. There are several countries in the world where the week starts on different days: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend#Around_the_world

Comment: Thx dude. I removed the wrong informations from the Post. So it will not spread :)